# Download in ionic/cordova app doesn't hit if I don't close/minimize the app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic/cordova app, I'm not really sure if the problem is `$ionicPlatform.ready` or `$cordovaFileTransfer.download`.  First things first, everything is working but there's a little problem, so I encountered this problem only in iOS.  `cordova.file.*` becomes **null** if the app has no permission to access the directory and/or if the app is not yet ready.  So to make the app always have the access to the persistent directory, `$cordovaFileTransfer.download` should be inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` or `document.addEventListener('deviceready',function())` but when I try to hit the download, the download doesn't start unless I minimize/close the app and open it again, (What I mean of minimize is when I hit the menu button twice).

Here's my shortened sample code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    try {
        $scope.download = function(videoInfo) {
            $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, MyFiles, {}, true).then(
                function(result) { //success download

                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Download Successful!',
                    });

                },
                function(error) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        template: JSON.stringify(error)
                    });
                },
                function(progress) {

                    //just some progress bar here
                });

        }).error(function() {
        alert("error");
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

} //end of button download

}
catch (err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
}

}) //end of ionicplatformready
```

Comment: it could be because background process will be block in your mobile..

Comment: so what's your recommendation?

Comment: go to setting and enable background process for your app

Comment: settings from iphone and my app? coz I tried navigating to it, but only location is there